Is LSF API lsb_submit thread safe?
My application is trying to submit jobs to LSF cluster with one lsb_submit call per thread. There are three threads running concurrently. The process is either terminating with segmentation fault at call to lsb_submit, or printing messages like:
Conflict parameter LSB_SUB_PROJECT_NAME - Ignored.
Conflict parameter LSB_SUB_JOB_DESCRIPTION - Ignored.
Conflict parameter LSB_SUB_USER_GROUP - Ignored.
Conflict parameter LM_PROJECT - Ignored.

The submissions successfully complete when lsb_submit is called sequentially on single thread.
Is lsb_submit not thread safe? Is there any way we can make the API thread safe? Is there a thread safe version?
Here is a minimal program to reproduce.
int func() {

    struct submit req;    
    memset(&req, 0, sizeof(req));
    struct submitReply  reply;  

    for (int i = 0; i < LSF_RLIM_NLIMITS; i++) {   
        req.rLimits[i] = DEFAULT_RLIMIT;
    }

    req.options = 0;
    req.options2 = 0;
    req.beginTime = 0;
    req.termTime  = 0;
    req.numProcessors = 1; 
    req.maxNumProcessors = 1;    

    std::string cmd = "ls"; 
    req.command = new char[cmd.size()+1];
    cmd.copy(req.command, cmd.size());
    req.command[cmd.size()] = '\0'; 
    
    int jobId = lsb_submit(&req, &reply);
    if (jobId < 0) {  
      std::cout << "\nFailed submit ";
      /*handle*/ 
    } else {
      std::cout << "\nSuccess submit ";
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    if (lsb_init(argv[0]) < 0) {
        lsb_perror(NULL);
        exit(-1);
    }

    std::vector<std::future<int>> vec;
    for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
      vec.push_back(std::launch::async, std::async(func));
    }
    std::cout << "\nOutput = " << vec[0].get();
    std::cout << "\nOutput = " << vec[1].get();
}


I am seeing different output with runs. Sometimes submissions happen without failure, at other times I see following issues:
$ ./a.out ls

*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00002ae760006440 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x81329)[0x2ae75a024329]
<>/lib/liblsf.so(+0x15253b)[0x2ae75910a53b]
<>/lib/liblsf.so(+0x152a9a)[0x2ae75910aa9a]
<>/lib/liblsf.so(callLimVarXdrSize_+0x650)[0x2ae75910bb70]
<>/lib/liblsf.so(callLim_+0x27)[0x2ae75910d417]
<>/lib/liblsf.so(+0x146e4a)[0x2ae7590fee4a]
<>/lib/liblsf.so(ls_getmastername+0x69)[0x2ae7590ff079]
<>/lib/libbat.so(getMasterName+0x170)[0x2ae758cae260]
<>/lib/libbat.so(+0xa5500)[0x2ae758c17500]
<>/lib/libbat.so(lsb_submit+0xeb)[0x2ae758c1b7eb]
./a.out[0x4036a3]
...

Or the following:
$ ./a.out ls

Aug  7 10:36:27 2024 32345 4 10.1 Conflict parameter LSB_SUB_PROJECT_NAME - Ignored.
Aug  7 10:36:27 2024 32345 4 10.1 Conflict parameter LSB_SUB_JOB_DESCRIPTION - Ignored.
Aug  7 10:36:27 2024 32345 4 10.1 Conflict parameter LM_PROJECT - Ignored.
Aug  7 10:36:27 2024 32345 4 10.1 Conflict parameter JOB_DESCRIPTION - Ignored.
Res = Job <480466> is submitted to default queue <>.

Success submit 1
Res = Job <480467> is submitted to default queue <>.

Success submit 1 


Please show a [mre]. It is supposed to be thread safe in itself, but if you use esub to modify the resource requirement at the same time as you call lsb_submit it could core dump in older versions of LSF.

@TedLyngmo I have added the minimal reproducible example. Could you take a look?

What if you add LS_LONG_INT thread_safe_lsb_submit(struct submit *jobSubReq, struct submitReply *jobSubReply) { static std::mutex mtx; std::lock_guard lock(mtx); return lsb_submit(jobSubReq, submitReply); } and call that function instead? Does that resolve the issue?

Btw, your program will leak memory since you use new[] but not delete[]. Why not do req.command = cmd.data(); instead of new[] and copy?

Another thing, you can simplify struct submit req; memset(&req, 0, sizeof(req)); by initializing req directly: submit req{};

@TedLyngmoc thread_safe_lsb_submit works successfully!

Ok, that was surprising, but still good that there's a workaround :-)

It seems that lsb_submit actually is not thread safe.
In order to make it possible to submit jobs from multiple threads, I suggest adding a proxy function to ensure that only one thread in your program calls lsb_submit simultaneously:
#include <mutex>

LS_LONG_INT thread_safe_lsb_submit(struct submit *jobSubReq,
                                   struct submitReply *jobSubReply)
{
    static std::mutex mtx;
    std::lock_guard lock(mtx);
    return lsb_submit(jobSubReq, jobSubReply);
}

